# how to get id of item selected in spinner and return int value

Tags: android

```
int txt= (int) parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position)
```

When i display `txt` variable in Toast my application makes crush and i need to get id of selected Item and then save that id in other table please help me

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, as well as the complete [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174).

Comment: what is the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         String id = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
     }

     @Override
     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

     }
});
```